# How to convert php template to Timber (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, timber

I'm fine creating a brand new Timber template, but I need to override a plugin template (MEC Events) - the plugin support give help with that but its in php, which works and brings in the header and footer from my base twig template, but doesn't include the `post.thumbnail` and `post.title` on those which it should.

In any case I'd like to keep the whole site in Timber/Twig ideally, but don't have a clue where to start turning this into a Timber template. Here's the php template, any help greatly appreciated:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single events
 */

get_header();

$single = new MEC_skin_single();
$single_event_main = $single->get_event_mec(get_the_ID());
$single_event_obj = $single_event_main[0];

// Date Widget
$single->display_date_widget($single_event_obj);
// Time Widget
$single->display_time_widget($single_event_obj);
// Location Widget
$single->display_location_widget($single_event_obj); // Show Location
// Label Widget
$single->display_label_widget($single_event_obj);
// Export Widget
$single->display_export_widget($single_event_obj);
//Social
$single->display_social_widget($single_event_obj);

get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not familiar with the MEC events calendar, but from looking at your code snippet, I think you could make it work, at least to a certain level.

You have these three lines, that kind of *prepare* the data that should be displayed in a template.

```php
$single = new MEC_skin_single();
$single_event_main = $single->get_event_mec(get_the_ID());
$single_event_obj = $single_event_main[0];
```

With Timber and Twig, you’ll want to prepare your data in PHP and then pass it to your Twig template. Here’s how I would do it.

```php
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();

$single            = new MEC_skin_single();
$single_event_main = $single->get_event_mec( get_the_ID() );

$context = array_merge( $context, [
    'single'           => $single,
    'single_event_obj' => $single_event_main[0],
] );

Timber::render( 'single-event.twig', $context );
```

**single-event.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    {# Date Widget #}
    {{ single.display_date_widget(single_event_obj) }}

    {# Time Widget #}
    {{ single.display_time_widget(single_event_obj) }}

    {# Location Widget #}
    {{ single.display_location_widget(single_event_obj) }}

    {# Label Widget #}
    {{ single.display_label_widget(single_event_obj) }}

    {# Export Widget #}  
    {{ single.display_export_widget(single_event_obj) }}

    {# Social #}
    {{ single.display_social_widget(single_event_obj) }}

{% endblock }
```

In Timber, you usually have a base template that you extend. And in that base template, you define blocks where your content is going to be placed in. That’s what the `{% extend %}` and `{% block %}` tags are for. With this, you can get rid of `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.

Because `$single` is an object with `display_*_widget()` methods, we can access that function through the dot notation. The methods need a `$single_event_obj` as a parameter, so we make sure this variable is also passed to the template data.

In case you now need access to `post.thumbnail` and `post.title`, you can also prepare a `post` variable in your PHP template:

```php
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();

$single            = new MEC_skin_single();
$single_event_main = $single->get_event_mec( get_the_ID() );

$context = array_merge( $context, [
    'post'             => Timber::get_post(),
    'single'           => $single,
    'single_event_obj' => $single_event_main[0],
] );

Timber::render( 'single-event.twig', $context );
```

Comment: thank you so much - at first I got an error, so re-read your explanation and just tried using {{ }} in the twig instead of {% %} and all works great (you're right, I was extending a base.twig template) - if you want to amend your answer to that I can tick it as answered

Comment: @iain-g I’m glad you got it working! Alright, so `{{` work and `{%` don’t. I changed that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again - $context = array_merge has helped my with another part of the site too - you're a star!